# The maximum number of length in mathematica

Tags: system-limitations

What is the maximum number that can be used with the following command in mathematica?

```
Length[IntegerDigits[x!]]
```

where 'x' is replaced by some finite integer for which the above command reaches its max number.

Then, what is this number?

Comment: Depends upon the amount of memory your system has.

Comment: @Andrew what is the dependence? i.e assume I have 'y' GB memory, then how would you answer my question? If there's an official answer even better.

Comment: Now you want a function :) I doubt there is an official one.

Comment: Look, people are in general sceptic if such a question is asked without any effort from yourself. Don't you have an educated guess what happens if `x` grows larger and larger? When will `x!` be so large that it fills your RAM? Can you estimate the how many digits it will have without calling `IntegerDigits`? Would theoretically `Length` have any problems giving you the number? These are easy questions you can answer yourself when you think about how a number is represented in memory.

Comment: @Andrew so how can I know what is the maximum number, surely I can compute it; why do you think there's not an official one?

Comment: Because nobody needed it? As for the estimate, the result of `IntegerDigits[x!]` should fit into the memory, so $\log_{10}x!$ probably should be less  (up to a constant) than amount of memory available to the kernel.

Comment: Just spitballing, but probably one should determine the number whose factorial is equal to `$MaxMachineNumber` or `$MaxNumber`, or the number whose factorial has ``Developer`$MaxMachineInteger`` digits..

Answer (score 8):

#### Crude estimates of memory limitations in `Length[IntegerDigits[n!]]`.

This is a game we can poke at empirically and draw lines that should hold up to some systematic breakdown invisible from low memory scales.  Best to work from the inside out as long as the memory constraints are dominated by outer layers.  This is reasonable as `IntegerDigits` will dominate `n!`.

I'll assume linear dependence but will fit with higher polynomial to verify small weights of higher orders.

---

```
facPlot = ListPlot[facData = Table[{x, ByteCount[x!]}, {x, 1, 10000}]]

facSol = FindFit[facData, facFunc = a + b x + c x^2, {a, b, c, d, e}, 
  x]
```

> {a -> -227.075, b -> 1.37349, c -> 0.000020072, d -> 0., e -> 0.}

---

```
Show[Plot[{0, facFunc /. facSol}, {x, 1, 10000}], facPlot]
```

[image: facFitPlot]

From the $b$ parameter let's say 1.5 bytes for every $n$ to store $n!$.   So if you have `15GB`, can estimate $n_{\rm max}(15GB)\sim 10^{10}$.

---

OK, what about integer digits.

```
idPlot = ListPlot[
  idData = Table[{x, ByteCount[IntegerDigits[x!]]}, {x, 1, 1000}]]

idSol = FindFit[idData, 
  idFunc = a  + b x   + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4 + f x^5, {a, b, c, d, e,
    f}, x]
```

> {a -> 151.424, b -> 6.97385, c -> 0.0667293, d -> -0.000152748, 
>    e -> 1.66995*10^-7, f -> -6.67819*10^-11}

```
Show[Plot[{0, idFunc /. idSol}, {x, 1, 1000}], idPlot]
```

[image: idFitPlot]

So let's say 8 bytes per `IntegerDigits[n!]`, so if you had `16GB`, $n_{\rm max}\sim 2\times 10^9$ .

Let's look at `Length` firmly believing that it offers no resource constraints relative to the other expenses.

```
lPlot = ListPlot[
  lData = Table[{x, ByteCount[Length[IntegerDigits[x!]]]}, {x, 1, 
     5000}]]
```

[image: length plot]

We see this isn't going to be the factor, it'll be the integerdigits that's expensive and the memory bound.

---

**Update:** I decided to use some sleepy cycles on a large memory machine to verify / see where this breaks down.  So far `ByteCount` measurements remains the same, *but* I noticed `top` was fluctuating a fair bit higher.

Wrapping `ByteCount` with `MaxMemoryUsed` seems to be giving a more `top`-related factor (still more or less linear)

- $\sim n\times (16 + 0.0154 \ln(n)^2) $ bytes  for `MaxMemoryUsed[ByteCount[n!]]` through $n\sim 6\times 10^9$ .  Data will be hosted and updated [here](https://gist.github.com/drjjmc/9d7759457a6d51f05d92911fbaee31b0) if you want to play with it.

[image: loglog Bytes Nfac vs N]
[image: loglin Bytes/n Nfac vs N]

- $\sim n \times 30$ bytes for  `MaxMemoryUsed[ByteCount[IntegerDigits[n!]]]`